Upgrading Android Studio again and again removes virtual devices - can one prevent this?
Mostly every other update or patch to Android Studio (e.g. I just applied "Patch 2" to Koala the other day) for some reason, removing my virtual device definitions. If it at least would told and/or warn you, but they are simply gone. Strange enough, it typically happens not immediately after the patch get applied but a few hours or so later or the next time you start Android Studio - pough - no more virtual device defined!  >:-( I am starting to really get fed up with this!
Can one somehow backup these definitions, so that I can later easily restore them, when this POS has again decided to remove my AVD? Where do these definitions sit?

Configured emulators and their images should be saved in ~/.android/avd.

@Robert Thanks and yes, meanwhile I also found that out. There is actually a "Show on Disk" command behind the entry (at the end of the three-dots-menu) in the device manager's list. Oddly, in my case, there is a corresponding entry below that path, so it's not gone or missing but - at least I have to guess so - it is probably corrupted or for whatever reason not usable which then obviously triggers Android Studio to just ignore it. I have created me a .zip of that directory and hope that next time this happens again, I can then simply recreate that directory to a (hopefully) usable state.
